# Redirecting from mobile website to googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, mobile, redirect, gps, directions

Basically what I want to do is, redirect the user from a mobile website to Google Maps on their phone and from there it will show the user the directions from their GPS location to my location.

What type of languages would be needed?

and

How difficult is it to find the GPS location and to auto fill it in on google maps?

Comment: I think, this will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703349/open-google-maps-app-from-a-browser-with-default-start-location-on-android-and-i

Comment: You could do it just with javascript. You may want to take a look at [this](http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH23.php)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: **Invoking Google Applications on Android Devices**
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Maybe the *geo:0,0?q=my+street+address* can be useful to you.