# Google maps - Javascript - How to enable click marker listener if is using a cellphone to active gps directions

Tags: google-maps-markers

I have a questions, currently I have in a webpage some markers that I get from a xml file using position of latitude and longitude.

So I would like to know how to enable to option of the marker listener to activate or show the option to send the user using the cellphone directions (gps). Like in android it I click on the marker it shows the option to activate gps directions, but on web I don't know how.

So for each direction if is clicked send the current position to the gps directions app of the cellphone.

Currlently I have this code:

```
function initMap() {


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 12
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});



    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }


      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('https://www.mysite/dataMaps.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            //map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

          });
        });
      });



    }
```

And

I foun this in google site:

```
        function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
      service.route({
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        waypoints: [{location: 'Adelaide, SA'}, {location: 'Broken Hill, NSW'}],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        avoidTolls: true
      }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          display.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
```

But in waypoints: not sure how to send the latitude and longitude parameters and if it will work on mobile devices to trigger the gps directions app :S

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I saw how, in the infowindow you just need to add this:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:<lat>,<lng>&navigate=yes">nav</a>
```

I found it here: [Is there a way to invoke navigation from mobile browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232273/is-there-a-way-to-invoke-navigation-from-mobile-browser)